# nth-child tag inside a second div isn't working, why

Tags: css-selectors

I have a code and simplified it for my question. I have a nth-child(2) css that works fine in the first example but not in the second. If I remove the 'empty' div it works fine. How to fix that with css and not remove the 'empty' div

```
<style>.av-special-heading-tag:nth-child(2) { background-color:#ff0; padding: 6px !important; text-transform:uppercase; }

</style>


<h1 class="av-special-heading-tag " itemprop="headline">Latest news</h1>
<h1 class="av-special-heading-tag " itemprop="headline">Latest news</h1>

<div id="blog" >
    <h1 class="av-special-heading-tag " itemprop="headline">Latest news</h1>
    <div>
        <h1 class="av-special-heading-tag " itemprop="headline">Latest news</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Solution more like this I think**

```
#blog .avia-builder-el-9 :nth-child(1) { background-color:#ff0; padding: 6px !important; text-transform:uppercase; }
#blog .avia-builder-el-12:nth-child(1) { background-color:#f00; padding: 6px !important; text-transform:uppercase; }</style>

<div id="blog" class="avia-section main_color avia-section-no-padding avia-no-border-styling avia-bg-style-scroll  avia-builder-el-7  el_after_av_section  el_before_av_section   container_wrap fullsize" style="background-image: ">


        <div style="padding-bottom:10px; " class="av-special-heading av-special-heading-h1  blockquote modern-quote  avia-builder-el-9  el_before_av_blog  avia-builder-el-first  ">
            <h1 class="av-special-heading-tag " itemprop="headline">LAATSTE NIEUWS</h1>
        </div>
        <div style="padding-bottom:10px; " class="av-special-heading av-special-heading-h1  blockquote modern-quote  avia-builder-el-12  el_before_av_textblock  avia-builder-el-first   ">
            <h1 class="av-special-heading-tag " itemprop="headline">HKL AGENDA</h1>
        </div>
```

but the second avia-builder-el-12 isn't turn red

Comment: But the div is not empty. It contains a child! The fourth h1 is the first child of the div! Anyway, if it worked the way you wanted, only the second h1 would be highlighted, not the fourth as well.

Comment: Oh, you want a solution in CSS.There are many. How about replacing the selector with `.av-special-heading-tag:first-child + *`.

Comment: Thanks it is clear now why it isn't working. Can not change the selector because it's generated by WP theme so that solution isn't a option

Comment: But you said you wanted a CSS solution because you couldn't change the HTML. If you can't change the CS either, then I'm afraid you're out of options.

Comment: Can you use JavaScript?

Comment: Yes I can add javascript